# Transfer learning on faster rcnn and tensorflow

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, transfer-learning

I am trying to do transfer learning to reuse a pretrained neural net. I got the tensorflow faster rcnn official example to work, and now i would like to reuse it to detect my own classes.

This is the repo im using https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

I have a dataset of ~2k images with 2 different classes. Just .JPG images in two different folders.

I could successfully do some transfer learning with this dataset on a CNN, using the official example of tensorflow. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#1

I am trying to understand how to do the same with this faster rcnn. Has anyone done it? I am a bit lost, can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm having basically a similar problem. It's much easier to retrain the final classification layer in an R-CNN then in a faster r-cnn (or in fast r-cnn or spp): this because in an R-CNN you basically have 2 disjoint part of the network, one proposing regions (R) and the other simply classifying each region as you do in a normal classification problem. 

I have been looking around for some repo allowing the retraining of the final classification FCN (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113465/r-cnn-looking-for-repo-where-fc-for-classification-is-retrainable) but no answer :(

Comment: let's help each other: I leave you my mail guerrinitom@gmail.com , if you find any repo or want to discuss how to implement it please send me an email :)

Comment: I am still having this problem. Any info you guys found please post it here. Ill do the same as soon as i find something